# Autowiring of custom ObjectMapper config in spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I'd like to centrally configure jackson ObjectMapper and use everywhere in my app the same ObjectMapper. What could possible be wrong in the following code that the DI doesn't work?

I added a CustomJacksonConfig.java to src/main/java/migrationtool/config:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomJacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper mapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }

}
```

And use it within some class:

```
public abstract class HcmsEntity implements JsonSerializable {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public JsonNode serialize() {
           return this.mapper.valueToTree(this);
    }
}
```

Concrete Class:

```
   public class Paragraph extends HcmsComponent{
      @JsonWrapped("content") // module to be extended in the CustomJacksonConfig
      public String text;
   }
```

unit test :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
public class ParagraphTest {

    @Test
    void serializeParagraph() {
        Paragraph paragraph = ParagraphMock.createParagraphWithID(1);
        paragraph.setIdentifier("p:1:1.p");

        assertThat(paragraph.serialize()).hasToString(ParagraphMock.getExpectedJson(1));

    }
 }
```

In the unittest which tests serialize()

> 10:08:00.693 [main] ERROR Paragraph - java.lang.NullPointerException:
> Cannot invoke
> "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.valueToTree(Object)"
> because "this.mapper" is null

Comment: I'm guessing you're not running the unit test with the spring runner or extension (which depends on which version of junit you're using). Please include the unit test.

Comment: I've added the unittest

Comment: What is `ParagraphMock.createParagraphWithID(..)`? Presumably it created an instance with `new` instead of through Spring, which means `mapper` is `null`.